# tuple - reasons for a separate header

Tags: c++

It's not a strictly programming question, but why was `tuple` defined in a separate header instead of being added to `<utility>` along with `pair`? It would seem more natural, less cluttered etc.

Comment: More natural than putting `tuple` in a header named `<tuple>`?

Comment: it's just a utility class, like there is no `pair` header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tension between having fine-grained headers and having just one header (e.g. `<all>` was proposed). Since compilers have to process the tokens within each header and some internal data structures also grow with the declarations seen (especially when the declarations use the same name like `operator<<()`), there is a compile-time trade-off. The original implementation of `tuple<T...>` came from [Boost](http://boost.org/) and predated the use of variadic templates: as a result, the declaration necessary to implement something like `tuple<T...>` were rather large. This caused `std::experimental::tuple<T...>` to be put into its own header and there wasn't any proposal to change this organization.

BTW, `std::tuple<...>` has *nothing* to do with [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library).